# Homework: Freeing data in a struct

Tags: c, struct

I'm just learning to use valgrind and c, and I have an invalid free() output when trying to free data from a struct. I believe it's because data is not being freed from the struct correctly.

This is my struct:

```
typedef struct song_
{
    char *artist;
    char *title;
    mtime *lastPlayed;
} song;
```

And this is the function which tries to free it:

```
void songDelete(song *s)
{
    //artist
    free(s->artist) ;
    //title
    free(s->title) ;
    //time
    if(NULL != s->lastPlayed)
        mtimeDelete(s->lastPlayed) ;
    //song
    free(s);
}
```

mtime and mtimeDelete are some user-defined variables and methods, but I feel like they're not relevant to my question. I know it's wrong to ask someone to do my homework for me, I'd just like a push in the right direction if possible.

Comment: what is that invalid output that you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's definitely the right way to do it.

So, if `valgrind` is complaining, it's probably because the values in `artist`, `title` or `lastPlayed` are not actually valid pointers.

That's the first thing I'd be checking.

In other words, make sure what you put *in* there are valid pointers. Simply creating a song with:

```
song *AchyBreakyHeart = malloc (sizeof (song));
```

won't populate the fields (they'll be set to arbitrary values). Similarly,

```
AchyBreakyHeart->artist = "Bill Ray Cyrus";
```

will populate it with a string constant rather than a valid pointer in the heap.

The ideal thing would be to have a "constructor", similar to the destructor you've provided, something like:

```
song *songCreate (char *artist, char *title, mtime *lastPlayed) {
    song *s = malloc (sizeof (song));
    if (s == NULL) return NULL;

    s->artist = strdup (artist);
    if (s->artist == NULL) {
        free (s);
        return NULL;
    }

    s->title = strdup (title);
    if (s->title == NULL) {
        free (s->artist);
        free (s);
        return NULL;
    }

    s->lastPlayed = mtimeDup (lastPlayed);
    if (s->lastPlayed == NULL) {
        free (s->title);
        free (s->artist);
        free (s);
        return NULL;
    }

    return s;
}
```

This guarantees that the object is either fully constructed or not constructed at all (ie, no half-states).

Better yet would be to adapt the constructor/destructor pair to handle NULLs in conjuction with each other, to simplify the pair. First, a slightly modified destructor, the only change being that it can accept NULL and ignore it:

```
void songDelete (song *s) {
    // Allow for 'songDelete (NULL)'.

    if (s != NULL) {
        free (s->artist);  // 'free (NULL)' is valid, does nothing.
        free (s->title);
        if (s->lastPlayed != NULL) {
            mtimeDelete (s->lastPlayed) ;
        }
        free (s);
    }
}
```

Next, the constructor which, rather than trying to remember what has been allocated, instead sets them all to NULL initially and just calls the destructor if something goes wrong:

```
song *songCreate (char *artist, char *title, mtime *lastPlayed) {
    // Create song, null all fields to ease destruction,
    //   then only return it if ALL allocations work.

    song *s = malloc (sizeof (song));
    if (s != NULL) {
        s->artist = s->title = s->lastPlayed = NULL;

        s->artist = strdup (artist);
        if (s->artist != NULL) {
            s->title = strdup (title);
            if (s->title != NULL) {
                s->lastPlayed = mtimeDup (lastPlayed);
                if (s->lastPlayed != NULL) {
                    return s;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // If ANY allocation failed, destruct the song and return NULL.

    songDelete (s);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check through and make sure I've done this right.

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears correct.

Make sure that your struct is initialized correctly (with pointers set to `NULL` or a valid value).

```
int main() {
    song_ *s = calloc(sizeof(song_));
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Asblarf There is no need to call `free(&s)`, because you `s` is not allcoted in heap.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create an object/pointer to your `Struct` using `malloc` (heap allocation)? or just `song s;` (stack allocation) ??

You can't free it if it hasn't been malloc'd, or in other words you can't free a variable on `stack`, it has to be on the `heap`.

Comment: Yes, it was definitely done with malloc. (Or it was supposed to be and I messed up. I'll check to make sure I'm always using malloc, though.)